# Which countries have employed rail biking in their armed forces?

Tags: history, draisine

Can anyone tell me which counties have employed [rail bikes](http://rrbike.freeservers.com/) in their armed forces? I remember seeing pictures of soldiers riding the rails on bikes, but cannot recall any details of them.

[image: Railbiking]

Rail biking on abandoned rail tracks!

[image: A railbike]

A rail bike set to go!

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Ken. Interesting question. While I do think it's on-topic for this site, you could try [history.se] if you don't get traction here. But please don't cross-post!

Comment: That looks very interesting - do you have one of these bikes with a rail kit?    Nowdays I expect a MTB would simply ride over the sleepers  and use the shocks to smooth the ride, so I strongly doubt any armed force uses this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShbC5yVqOdI#t=186

Comment: @KenGraham Cross posting is when we post the same item in more than one place.

Comment: Here's a place they still use them - http://www.flekkefjordbanen.no/

Comment: I recall reading of some use of this by the US Army in the early days of WWI.  But I don't think it was ever more than an experiment.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Military History Journal](http://samilitaryhistory.org/vol041dm.html) (Volume 4 No 1 - June 1977) there is an article entitled **BICYCLES IN THE ANGLO-BOER WAR OF 1899-1902**, by D.R. Maree, which seems to fit this question.

[image: The War Cicycle.]

The 'War Cycle' carried several men on the coupling-framework in addition to the eight riders,
 could be fitted with a Maxim gun, and was capable of a speed of over 48 kmh.
 Photo: Africana Museum

> A special 'War Cycle' was built for use on railway lines, and a prototype of this 8-man bicycle can be seen at Fort Klapperkop Museum. It was introduced into South Africa by the Royal Australian Cycle Corps and had a detachable rim which was fitted to the pneumatic tires, enabling it to be used on rails. When the rim was removed the bicycle could be used on normal roads. These cycles were used for reconnaissance, for carrying despatches, checking the railway line for demolition charges, and also for removing the wounded from a skirmish taking place near a railway.